# Configure resource limits in a pod via cli

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to run a pod where the default limit of my **GKE AutoPilot Cluster is 500m vCPU**.. But I want to run all my pods by 250m vCPU only. I tried the command `kubectl run pod-0 --requests="cpu=150m" --restart=Never --image=example/only`

But I get a warning: `Flag --requests has been deprecated, has no effect and will be removed in the future`. Then when I describe my pod, it sets `500m`. I would like to know option to set resource limits with just plainly `kubectl run pod`

Comment: Oops my mistake, `--limit=cpu=250m` is working

Answer (score 3):

Since kubectl v1.21 All generators are deprecated.

Github issue: [Remove generators from kubectl commands](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/93100) quote:

> kubectl command are going to get rid of the dependency on the
> generators, and ultimately remove them entirely. **The main goal is to
> simplify the use of kubectl command**. This is already done in kubectl
> run, see [#87077](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/87077) and [#68132](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/68132).

So it looks like `--limits` and `--requests` flags willn't longer be available in the future.

Here is the PR that did it: [Drop deprecated run flags and deprecate unused ones](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/99732).

Comment: "The main goal is to simplyfy the use of kubectl command" Simplify!! The syntax for specifying limits using overrides is anything but simple!